# compute avg in every previous group number

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to compute sog average in every previous group.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(grp = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3,
                     4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6,
                     6, 7, 7, 7, 8),
             
             sog = c(12.00, 12.00, 12.00, 11.00, 10.00,
                     9.00,  2.00,  8.80,  8.70,  7.80,
                     11.00 ,11.00, 12.00, 11.00, 9.54,
                     9.80, 10.40,  4.00,  4.00,  4.50,
                     3.60,  7.00, 8.00,  9.00,  0.00),
             
             res = c(NA,NA,NA ,NA, NA,NA, NA ,
                     0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ,0,0,0,
                     66.66667, 66.66667,66.66667, 66.66667,
                     275.0, 275.0, 275.0, 0)
)
```

I want something like:

```
df %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    mutate(sog_avg = dplyr::lag(mean(sog), n = 'by every previous group', default = NA))
```

Data now is:

```
 grp   sog   res

 1     12     NA  
 1     12     NA  
 1     12     NA  
 1     11     NA  
 1     10     NA  
 1      9     NA  
 2      2     NA  
 3     8.8    0  
 3     8.7    0  
 3     7.8    0  
 4     11      0  
 4     11      0  
 4     12      0  
 4     11      0  
 5     9.54   0  
 5     9.8    0  
 5     10.4    0  
 6     4     66.7
 6     4     66.7
 6     4.5   66.7
 6     3.6   66.7
 7     7    275  
 7     8    275  
 7     9    275  
 8     0      0
```

The result I want is:

```
 grp   sog   res  sog_avg

 1     12     NA  NA
 1     12     NA  NA
 1     12     NA  NA
 1     11     NA  NA
 1     10     NA  NA
 1      9     NA  NA
 2      2     NA  11
 3     8.8    0    2
 3     8.7    0    2
 3     7.8    0    2
 4     11     0   8.43
 4     11     0   8.43 
 4     12     0   8.43
 4     11     0   8.43
 5     9.54   0   11.25
 5     9.8    0   11.25
 5     10.4   0   11.25
 6     4     66.7 9.91
 6     4     66.7 9.91
 6     4.5   66.7 9.91 
 6     3.6   66.7 9.91
 7     7    275   4.025 
 7     8    275   4.025
 7     9    275   4.025
 8     0      0   8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can calculate mean for every group, shift it back one step using `lag` and then join the data :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(sog_avg = mean(sog, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(sog_avg = lag(sog_avg)) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'grp')

#   grp sog_avg   sog   res
#1    1      NA 12.00    NA
#2    1      NA 12.00    NA
#3    1      NA 12.00    NA
#4    1      NA 11.00    NA
#5    1      NA 10.00    NA
#6    1      NA  9.00    NA
#7    2   11.00  2.00    NA
#8    3    2.00  8.80   0.0
#9    3    2.00  8.70   0.0
#10   3    2.00  7.80   0.0
#11   4    8.43 11.00   0.0
#12   4    8.43 11.00   0.0
#13   4    8.43 12.00   0.0
#14   4    8.43 11.00   0.0
#15   5   11.25  9.54   0.0
#16   5   11.25  9.80   0.0
#17   5   11.25 10.40   0.0
#18   6    9.91  4.00  66.7
#19   6    9.91  4.00  66.7
#20   6    9.91  4.50  66.7
#21   6    9.91  3.60  66.7
#22   7    4.03  7.00 275.0
#23   7    4.03  8.00 275.0
#24   7    4.03  9.00 275.0
#25   8    8.00  0.00   0.0
```

Comment: Hi, if you want to  check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411133/average-in-previous-group-at-the-same-place-with-another-column a similar one, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option with the addition of `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(sog_avg = map_dbl(.x = grp - 1, ~ mean(sog[grp == .x]))) 

     grp   sog   res sog_avg
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1  12      NA     NaN
 2     1  12      NA     NaN
 3     1  12      NA     NaN
 4     1  11      NA     NaN
 5     1  10      NA     NaN
 6     1   9      NA     NaN
 7     2   2      NA      11
 8     3   8.8     0       2
 9     3   8.7     0       2
10     3   7.8     0       2
```

Or with just `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(grp) %>%
 mutate(sog_avg = mean(sog)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate(sog_avg = lag(sog_avg)) %>%
 group_by(grp) %>%
 mutate(sog_avg = first(sog_avg)) 

     grp   sog   res sog_avg
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1  12      NA      NA
 2     1  12      NA      NA
 3     1  12      NA      NA
 4     1  11      NA      NA
 5     1  10      NA      NA
 6     1   9      NA      NA
 7     2   2      NA      11
 8     3   8.8     0       2
 9     3   8.7     0       2
10     3   7.8     0       2
```

Comment: Hi, if you want to check a similar one , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411133/average-in-previous-group-at-the-same-place-with-another-column