# average in previous group at the same place with another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data and I am dividing the mdo value by the count number of mdo instances in the previous group.

I am calculating the sog avg also.

But I want to calculate the sog avg that takes place to the same instances as the result (mdo/count) value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(mydate = as.Date(c("2019-05-11 23:01:00", "2019-05-11 23:02:00", "2019-05-11 23:03:00", "2019-05-11 23:04:00",
                                "2019-05-12 23:05:00", "2019-05-12 23:06:00", "2019-05-12 23:07:00", "2019-05-12 23:08:00",
                                "2019-05-13 23:09:00", "2019-05-13 23:10:00", "2019-05-13 23:11:00", "2019-05-13 23:12:00",
                                "2019-05-14 23:13:00", "2019-05-14 23:14:00", "2019-05-14 23:15:00", "2019-05-14 23:16:00",
                                "2019-05-15 23:17:00", "2019-05-15 23:18:00", "2019-05-15 23:19:00", "2019-05-15 23:20:00",
                                "2019-05-15 23:21:00", "2019-05-15 23:22:00", "2019-05-15 23:23:00", "2019-05-15 23:24:00",
                                "2019-05-15 23:25:00")),
             mdo = c(1500, 1500, 1500, 1500,
                     1500, 1500, NA, 0,
                     0, 0, 900, 900, NA, NA, 1100, 1100,
                     1100, 200, 200, 200,200,
                     1100, 1100, 1100, 0
             ),
             sog = c(12, 12, 12, 11, 10,9,
                     2,8.8, 8.7, 7.8, 11, 11, 12, 11,
                     9.54, 9.8, 10.4,4, 4, 4.5, 3.6,
                     7, 8, 9, 0))

df1 <- df %>%
    mutate(grp = data.table::rleid(mdo))

df1 <- df1 %>%
    #Keep only non-NA value
    filter(!is.na(mdo)) %>%
    #count occurence of each grp
    count(grp, name = 'count') %>%
    #Shift the count to the previous group
    mutate(count = lag(count)) %>%
    #Join with the original data
    right_join(df1, by = 'grp') %>%
    arrange(grp)

group_mdo <- df1 %>%
    select(grp, mdo) %>%
    unique() %>%
    mutate(prev_mdo = lag(mdo, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
    select(-mdo) %>%
    tidyr::fill(prev_mdo, .direction = "down")


df1 <- df1 %>%
    left_join(group_mdo, by = "grp") %>%
    mutate(result = ifelse(prev_mdo != 0, mdo / count, 0)) %>%
    mutate(sog_avg = ifelse(prev_mdo != 0, map_dbl(.x = grp - 1, ~ mean(sog[grp == .x], na.rm=TRUE), na.rm=TRUE), NA))
```

The result right now is:

```
grp count    mydate       mdo   sog prev_mdo result sog_avg
 1    NA    2019-05-11   1500    12    NA     NA     NA  
 1    NA    2019-05-11   1500    12    NA     NA     NA  
 1    NA    2019-05-11   1500    12    NA     NA     NA  
 1    NA    2019-05-11   1500    11    NA     NA     NA  
 1    NA    2019-05-12   1500    10    NA     NA     NA  
 1    NA    2019-05-12   1500     9    NA     NA     NA  
 2    NA    2019-05-12     NA     2    1500   NA     11  
 3     6    2019-05-12     0     8.8   1500   0      2  
 3     6    2019-05-13     0     8.7   1500   0      2  
 3     6    2019-05-13     0     7.8   1500   0      2  
 4     3    2019-05-13   900     11    0      0      NA  
 4     3    2019-05-13   900     11    0      0      NA  
 5    NA    2019-05-14     NA    12    900    NA     11  
 5    NA    2019-05-14     NA    11    900    NA     11  
 6     2    2019-05-14   1100    9.54  900   550    11.5
 6     2    2019-05-14   1100    9.8   900   550    11.5
 6     2    2019-05-15   1100    10.4  900   550    11.5
 7     3    2019-05-15   200     4      1100  66.7   9.91
 7     3    2019-05-15   200     4     1100   66.7   9.91
 7     3    2019-05-15   200     4.5   1100   66.7   9.91
 7     3    2019-05-15   200     3.6   1100   66.7   9.91
 8     4    2019-05-15   1100    7     200    275    4.03
 8     4    2019-05-15   1100    8     200    275    4.03
 8     4    2019-05-15   1100    9     200    275    4.03
 9     3    2019-05-15     0     0     1100     0      8
```

My desired result:

```
  grp count    mydate       mdo   sog prev_mdo result sog_avg
     1    NA    2019-05-11   1500    12    NA     NA     NA  
     1    NA    2019-05-11   1500    12    NA     NA     NA  
     1    NA    2019-05-11   1500    12    NA     NA     NA  
     1    NA    2019-05-11   1500    11    NA     NA     NA  
     1    NA    2019-05-12   1500    10    NA     NA     NA  
     1    NA    2019-05-12   1500     9    NA     NA     NA  
     2    NA    2019-05-12     NA     2    1500   NA     NA  
     3     6    2019-05-12     0     8.8   1500   0      0  
     3     6    2019-05-13     0     8.7   1500   0      0  
     3     6    2019-05-13     0     7.8   1500   0      0  
     4     3    2019-05-13   900     11    0      0      0  
     4     3    2019-05-13   900     11    0      0      0  
     5    NA    2019-05-14     NA    12    900    NA     NA  
     5    NA    2019-05-14     NA    11    900    NA     NA  
     6     2    2019-05-14   1100    9.54  900   550    11
     6     2    2019-05-14   1100    9.8   900   550    11
     6     2    2019-05-15   1100    10.4  900   550    11
     7     3    2019-05-15   200     4     1100  66.7   9.91
     7     3    2019-05-15   200     4     1100   66.7   9.91
     7     3    2019-05-15   200     4.5   1100   66.7   9.91
     7     3    2019-05-15   200     3.6   1100   66.7   9.91
     8     4    2019-05-15   1100    7     200    275    4.03
     8     4    2019-05-15   1100    8     200    275    4.03
     8     4    2019-05-15   1100    9     200    275    4.03
     9     3    2019-05-15     0     0     1100     0      0
```

Where result is zero, sog_avg should be zero, where result is na, sog avg should be na.

And where result is being computed by using the previous group counts, sog avg should be computed with it's previous values.

So, for example:

mdo = 1100 , result is 550 because counts in previous non null group are 2 (mdo value 900).

1100 / 2 = 550 . At this point sog avg should be (11 + 11) / 2 = 11 because counts were 2 in the previous non null group.

Comment: Do you need `df1 %>% mutate(sog_avg = ifelse(is.na(result) | result == 0, result, sog_avg))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah:Hi, no I don't want this. I want to correctly compute sog_avg as I said and then ok, if result is nan or zero , yes

Comment: what do you want to do when you write `lag(mdo, na.rm=TRUE)`? `dplyr::lag` doesn't have a argument called `na.rm = `

Comment: @Edo:Yes, you are right, you can ignore that though.

Comment: why is count `NA` for `grp == 5` ? I think it doesn't make sense. It should be 2.

Comment: @Edo:Because mdo there is NA.When is NA , you don't count the previous group elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach. It extensively uses the idea of making groups by using base `table` or `tapply` and then lags those results. Note, this answer would fail if `mdo` is not constant throughout a group.

```r
library(data.table)

dt = as.data.table(df)

dt[, grp := rleid(mdo)]

dt[!is.na(mdo), 
   count := {
      cnt = table(grp)
      rep(shift(cnt), cnt)
      }
   ]

setcolorder(dt, c("grp", "count", "mydate", "mdo", "sog"))

dt[,
   prev_mdo := {
     ord = table(grp)
     nafill(rep(shift(mdo[cumsum(ord)]), ord), "locf")
     }
   ]


dt[, result := fifelse(prev_mdo != 0L, mdo / count, 0)]

dt[!is.na(result),
   sog_avg := {
     mn = tapply(sog, grp, mean)
     rep(shift(mn), table(grp))
   }]

dt[result == 0 | is.na(result), sog_avg := result]
dt
#>     grp count     mydate  mdo   sog prev_mdo    result   sog_avg
#>  1:   1    NA 2019-05-11 1500 12.00       NA        NA        NA
#>  2:   1    NA 2019-05-11 1500 12.00       NA        NA        NA
#>  3:   1    NA 2019-05-11 1500 12.00       NA        NA        NA
#>  4:   1    NA 2019-05-11 1500 11.00       NA        NA        NA
#>  5:   1    NA 2019-05-12 1500 10.00       NA        NA        NA
#>  6:   1    NA 2019-05-12 1500  9.00       NA        NA        NA
#>  7:   2    NA 2019-05-12   NA  2.00     1500        NA        NA
#>  8:   3     6 2019-05-12    0  8.80     1500   0.00000  0.000000
#>  9:   3     6 2019-05-13    0  8.70     1500   0.00000  0.000000
#> 10:   3     6 2019-05-13    0  7.80     1500   0.00000  0.000000
#> 11:   4     3 2019-05-13  900 11.00        0   0.00000  0.000000
#> 12:   4     3 2019-05-13  900 11.00        0   0.00000  0.000000
#> 13:   5    NA 2019-05-14   NA 12.00      900        NA        NA
#> 14:   5    NA 2019-05-14   NA 11.00      900        NA        NA
#> 15:   6     2 2019-05-14 1100  9.54      900 550.00000 11.000000
#> 16:   6     2 2019-05-14 1100  9.80      900 550.00000 11.000000
#> 17:   6     2 2019-05-15 1100 10.40      900 550.00000 11.000000
#> 18:   7     3 2019-05-15  200  4.00     1100  66.66667  9.913333
#> 19:   7     3 2019-05-15  200  4.00     1100  66.66667  9.913333
#> 20:   7     3 2019-05-15  200  4.50     1100  66.66667  9.913333
#> 21:   7     3 2019-05-15  200  3.60     1100  66.66667  9.913333
#> 22:   8     4 2019-05-15 1100  7.00      200 275.00000  4.025000
#> 23:   8     4 2019-05-15 1100  8.00      200 275.00000  4.025000
#> 24:   8     4 2019-05-15 1100  9.00      200 275.00000  4.025000
#> 25:   9     3 2019-05-15    0  0.00     1100   0.00000  0.000000
#>     grp count     mydate  mdo   sog prev_mdo    result   sog_avg
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for helping. For group 6 the right result is 11 because it is reffering to mdo values 900 where sog is 11 for both entries. This happens because group 5 has `na` mdo values, so when this is the case, we go up to the previous non na group (where mdo is not na).And this is group 4 which has mdo 900 and sog in both cases is 11. I hope that helps

Comment: Even though I load data.table library, it keeps showing error could not find  function nafill and fifelse !

Comment: Can you install it again? These are newer functions so you likely have am older version of the package

Comment: I have installed version 1.12.2 and still the same problem

Comment: Ok, I saw that it needs version 1.13, so I installed from github and runs ok! Code seems correct! Thanks! (upv)